# Upload photo to facebook using Rest API

Tags: php, facebook

Can you please have a look to this URL

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/photos.upload/

I need to have a working example, how can I use this api to upload a photo to my facebook profile.

Actually I have a php site from where I want to allow users to upload photo to their facebook profile.

Thank you

Comment: I need to upload photo to facebook using facebook Rest API. the developer page that shows the possibilities about how to upload photo to facebook profile.

Comment: As I know Stackoverflow is now answers to the question related facebook. So I refer to the link about which I need help. Please check the photo.upload function from REST API of Facebook, I need to use it, but have no idea, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link you posted refers to an outdated approach to FB API. It's better to use the Graph API in conjunction with the latest PHP SDK.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/
https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk

here's a reference to the photo object methods
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/

Here's a fairly recent example from the facebook developers blog:
http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498/